# Calculated fields in Laravel using Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

I've been working in a Laravel Project and I want to know how can I show a calculated field in a blade view? I want to retrieve some information from an invoice and a Total calculated field.

I would like to get this result, but using Eloquent ORM. The query is this:

```
SELECT 
    invoiceheader.id, 
    invoiceheader.customerlastname,
    invoiceheader.customerfirstname, 
    invoiceheader.customernit,
    invoicedetail.productid, 
    invoicedetail.quantity,
    invoicedetail.saleprice, 
    (quantity * saleprice) as Total
FROM invoiceheader 
INNER JOIN invoicedetail
    ON invoiceheader.id = invoicedetail.invoiceid
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use laravels `DB::raw()`, which injects the string to the query, like so:

[Laravel raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

```
InvoiceHeader::select('invoiceheader.id', 'invoiceheader.customerlastname',
   'invoiceheader.customerfirstname', 'invoiceheader.customernit', 
   'invoicedetail.productid', 'invoicedetail.quantity', 
   'invoicedetail.saleprice', DB::raw('(quantity * saleprice) as Total'))
->join('invoicedetail', 'invoiceheader.id', '=', 'invoicedetail.invoiceid')
->get();
```

Note: make sure to import `use DB;` on the top of the page

Comment: Thank you, one more thing. How may I show this new field in a table, in the View?

Comment: you can call it by the alias given `Total`

Comment: This exception appears when trying to load the view calling the alias. Undefined property: stdClass::$Total. Any suggestion?

Comment: What exection? Do you have use DB; on the top of the page of the controller?

Comment: Yes, I've already set use DB; at the top of the controller page. It shows me this message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Total

Comment: @krlosfgx can you update on your question, the view, the code quere you are trying to display

Comment: I just solved the issue. It was a model inconvenient, but it's working well right now. Thank you so much for your help. Greetings!

Comment: No problem, please mark as answer if this post helped

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by utlizing Eloquent relations and accessors.

In your `InvoiceHeader` model:

```
/*
Relation with the invoicedetail table
 */
public function detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne(InvoiceDetail::class, 'invoiceid', 'id');
}
```

In your `InvoiceDetail` model:

```
/*
The accessor field
 */
protected $appends = ['total_price'];

/*
Accessor for the total price
 */
public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->quantity * $this->saleprice;
}
```

To understand the created accessor name from the method name, here's a text from the laravel docs:

> To define an accessor, create a getFooAttribute method on your model
>   where Foo is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access.
>   In this example, we'll define an accessor for the first_name
>   attribute. The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when
>   attempting to retrieve the value of the first_name attribute:

For your query you could do:

```
// get all invoices in descending order of creation
$invoices = InvoiceHeader::recent()->get();

// loop invoice data to get the desired fields
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    $customerfirstname = $invoice->customerfirstname;

    $totalprice = $invoice->detail->total_price;

    // more code
}
```

You can read more about Accessors & Mutators on the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). Read about eloquent relations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Thank you, why does detail call total_price attribute?

Comment: The `total_price` attribute should have been on the `InvoiceDetail` model. I have fixed it now. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
InvoiceHeader::join("invoicedetail",function($query){
    $query->on("invoiceheader.id", "=", "invoicedetail.invoiceid")
})
->select("invoiceheader.id", 
         "invoiceheader.customerlastname",
         "invoiceheader.customerfirstname", 
         "invoiceheader.customernit",
         "invoicedetail.productid", 
         "invoicedetail.quantity",
         "invoicedetail.saleprice", 
\DB::raw("(invoicedetail.quantity * invoicedetail.saleprice) as Total"))
->get();
```

Comment: This is in the controller, isn't it?

Comment: Yes in the controller